# Check if element equality for different container types in Google Test

Tags: c++, stl, googletest

I want to check if the elements in two containers of different types are the same. However, when I use the `ContainerEq` matcher of the GoogleTest library it gives me an error that it can not initialize the vector from the array:

```
TEST(TestExample, Example) {
    std::array<int, 4> ar = {1,2,3,4};
    std::vector<int> v(ar.begin(), ar.end());

    EXPECT_THAT(ar, ::testing::ContainerEq(v));
}
```

Error message:

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'testing::internal::ContainerEqMatcher<std::vector<int> >::StlContainerReference' {aka 'const std::vector<int>&'} from expression of type 'const type' {aka 'const std::array<int, 4>'}
```

What options do I have to check for equality in different containers except for switching to `EXPECT_TRUE` and using std::equal?

Comment: [`::testing::ElementsAreArray(v)`](https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/matchers.html#container-matchers)?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Wow, missed that matcher :D. Thanks a lot! If you want to post an answer, I will accept it

Comment: Hmm, I was looking for a duplicate, but I can't find anything. I'll post na answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare elements of different containers using [`::testing::ElementsAreArray(v)`](https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/matchers.html#container-matchers):

```
TEST(TestExample, Example) {
    std::array<int, 4> ar = {1,2,3,4};
    std::vector<int> v(ar.begin(), ar.end());

    EXPECT_THAT(ar, ::testing::ElementsAreArray(v));
}
```